# input to size variable error in stack (c++)

Tags: c++, data-structures, cin

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct stack{
    int size;
    int top;
    int *s;
};

void create(struct stack *st){
    cout<<"enter size :";
    cin>>(&st->size);      ///This line poses error when i run the program
    st->top=-1;
    st->s=new int[st->size*sizeof(int)];
}

void display(struct stack st)
{
    for(int i:(st->s)){
        cout<<i;
    }
}
```

in the create function, when the compiler tries to take an input it shows error that "error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}’ and ‘int*’)". The error is not understandable. can anyone help in resolving the issue?

Comment: This program is just asking for a memory leak. Avoid owning bare pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&st->size` is an `int*`. You can't read from `cin` into an `int*`. Since you just need to read the size, removing the `&` should fix it:

```
cin >> st->size;
```

Your `for` loop in `display` is incorrect as well. You need to do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    cout << st->s[i];
```

Also, this line:

```
st->s=new int[st->size*sizeof(int)];
```

seems odd. If you want to have `st->size` elements in the array, then you just need:

```
st->s = new int[st->size];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also corrected the other parts. The information was useful.